# JSON with Listview

Tags: android, json, listview

I am new to android and i want to fetch the data from server using JSON and want to arrange in a listview but I am unable to do this. Here is the link : i. http://www.masjid-timetable.com/data/masjids.php!
[I want to arrange the data in this image format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5WRw.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background">

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        >
```

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="376dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/select_masjid"

            android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dashboard_n3"
    android:onClick="M"/>

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="300dp"
    android:background="@drawable/reload4"
   />
   </FrameLayout>
    </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_column="0">

       <FrameLayout>
       <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_all"
        android:layout_marginLeft="310dp"/>
    </FrameLayout>

        </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"

        android:layout_column="0">


    <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            >
            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:fastScrollEnabled="true"/>





        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/sideIndex"
                android:layout_width="40dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
     </TableLayout>

       </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try this website, http://www.skholingua.com/android-basic/other-sdk-n-libs/json-parsing

Answer (score 0):

You can get an easy to understand example for encoding and parsing json with the following reference links:

[Android JSON Tutorial: Create and Parse JSON data](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-json-tutorial-create-and-parse-json-data.html)

and

[JSON in Android - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON data from server will serve LIstView, then you better create a data class that will store list item data, so when you parse JSON, save each item to the data class. Then after parsing you will get a List/ArrayList of data class. Now you can show the data list in your ListView.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create one model class and then create one adapter to bind you response values, then you can use `Volley`,`Asynctask`,`Retrofit` to parse data.and then display it in your `listview`,[This](http://androidcss.com/android/fetch-json-data-android/) is exactly what you looking for